# Create shortcuts for methods in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to generate my out shortcuts, like `sout` or `soutv` and so on, in Android Studio ? I'd like to make something like `mab` and then press `ctrl+spaced` which will generate a predefined method and then let me fill out the params for it. (so basically the same as `sout`)

Comment: yes, they;re called live templates, https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/idea-live-templates

Comment: please write your comment as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, they're called Live Templates,

here is an example of someone doing it 
https://github.com/manhluong/peng/blob/master/PengAndroid/src/com/luongbui/peng/android/InstallWatchAppTask.java#L50

Here is the IntelliJ docs

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html

> To create a new template from scratch
>
> In the Settings dialog, open the Live Templates page, and expand the
>   template group where you want to create a new template.
>
> Click add (+).
>   A new template item is added to the group and the focus moves to the
>   Template Text area.
>
> Specify the new template abbreviation, type the
>   template body, define the variables and the template group, configure
>   the options, as described in the template modification procedure.
>
> Click OK when ready.

[image: lt]